# Extracting a single line value from a multi-line string T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a multi-line nvarchar that contains a string in the below format:

```
@String =  
'ReportHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255} 
ReportBodyHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportBodyFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}'
```

I want to be able to use a nvarchar value @Attribute = 'ReportHeaderFontColor' and extract just the line from @String that contains the @Attribute value

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You should probably consider using a proper format such as JSON or XML, for which there are built in parsing methods

Answer (score 1):

How about the following using `apply` to find the begin/end positions to find and `substring` to extract:

```
declare @Attribute nvarchar(100)= 'ReportHeaderFontColor',

@String nvarchar(max) =
'ReportHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178}
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}
ReportBodyHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178}
ReportBodyFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}';

with s as (select @string as string)
select Substring(string,b.pos,e.pos-b.pos+1)
from s
cross apply(values(charindex(Concat('ReportBodyHeaderColor','{'), string)))b(pos)
cross apply(values(CharIndex('}', string, b.pos)))e(pos)
where b.pos>0;
```

Result:

> ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach

**Example**

```
Declare @String varchar(max)=  
'ReportHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178}
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}
ReportBodyHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178}
ReportBodyFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}'

Declare @Find varchar(150) = 'ReportHeaderFontColor'

Select value
 From  string_split(replace(replace(@String,'}','}|'),char(13)+char(10),''),'|')
 where charindex(@Find,value)>0
```

**Results**

```
value
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split the string by line feed `char(10)` and then remove carriage return `char(13)` as follows:

```
Declare @Attribute nVarChar(50)= 'ReportHeaderFontColor'
Declare @String nVarChar(max) =  
'ReportHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255} 
ReportBodyHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportBodyFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}'

Select Replace(Value,Char(13),'') As Result
From String_Split(@String,Char(10))
Where Value Like Concat('%',@Attribute,'%')
```

| Result |
| --- |
| ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255} |

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions, unfortunately I am not able to use string_split as some of our clients are on systems older than SQL 2016.

After toying around for a little bit I was able to come up with the below solution which i placed inside a UDF and added some error checking:

```
declare @header_row nvarchar(max) = 
'ReportHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportHeaderFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255} 
ReportBodyHeaderColor{R:98, B:183, G:178} 
ReportBodyFontColor{R:255, B:255, G:255}'

declare @Attribute nvarchar(max) = 'ReportHeaderFontColor'

declare @String nvarchar(255)

-- check that the header row is not empty and actually contains the attribute
if (len(@header_row) = 0 or @header_row not like '%' + @Attribute + '%')
begin
    select @String = null
end
else begin

    select @String = 
        replace(replace(replace(
            left(
                substring(@header_row,charindex(@Attribute + '{', @header_row) + len(@Attribute + '{'), 999),charindex('}',
                substring(@header_row,charindex(@Attribute + '{', @header_row) + len(@Attribute + '{'), 999))-1)
        ,'R:',''),'G:',''),'B:','')

    -- if the string is not in the correct format(3 integers separated by a comma) set @String to null
    if (select count(1)
        from dbo.fn_ListToTable(@String,',') x
        where ISNUMERIC(x.List) = 1 and x.List <= 255) <> 3
    begin
        set @String = null
    end

end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).